# How to select the maximum occurring string from a list of lists?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, select, oracle11g, cx-oracle

In my database, I have a table.

```
statement= """create table itags(
                tag_id number(10) not null primary key,
                tag_name varchar2(50) 
                )"""
cur.execute(statement)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO itags VALUES(301,'Art')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO itags VALUES(302,'Science')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO itags VALUES(303,'Music')")
...
so on and so forth
...
```

Now I want to select and print the most widely occurring tag name.

If I do this:

```
cur.execute("select tag_name from itags")
res= cur.fetchall()
print(res)
```

I will get a list of tuples containing the tag names I have stored in that table.
ex: 
[(Art,),(Science,),(Music,),....]

Now how should I go about extracting the string with the maximum occurrence from this list of tuples? Also, will a SQL command be more helpful than a python code to do it?

Comment: Data summary is best done in the data layer.  Think about it if there were 10 million records you had to process locally, the data would have to be transmitted locally and then summarized.  IF you push the work to the database, the data already resides there and can "summarize" the data sending 1 record.  Not only will your user be happier, your network admins will be as well.  So a SQL command will be much more helpful than python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does all the heavy lifting for you with [`stats_mode`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions188.htm#SQLRF06320):

```sql
SELECT STATS_MODE(tag_name) FROM itags
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Please tell me from where can I learn about these oracle and sql functions?

Comment: You can start with Oracle's [SQL reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm)

Comment: Or just click the +  in front of functions on the left navigation in stats_mode link above.